# Selenium WebDriver verify the object (chat window) is displayed at the bottom left hand corner of the browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Can Selenium WebDriver verify the object (eg. small chat window) is displayed at the `bottom left hand corner` of the browser?

I know how to verity object is exist on the page with using, but not the location on the browser

```
Boolean isChatWindowExists = driver.findElements(By.id("chatWindowID")).size()!=0;
if(isChatWindowExists == true){
    System.out.println("Passed. Chat window is displayed at the bottom left hand corner of the browser");
}else{
    System.out.println("Failed. Chat window is not displayed at the bottom left hand corner of the browser");
}
```

Any idea how to perform verify action in Selenium WebDriver Java. Thanks.
Also, it will be testing at different workstation with different resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I have some work around for this,
As you can find the `x, y, coordinate of the element which is there just above or before the chat window and the position should be static`.

After that you can write the XPath for ur chat window and get the X, Y coordinates of chat window as follow

```
int x= driver.findElement (By.xpath("xpath of the elemt")).getLocation.GetX().
int y= driver.findElement (By.xpath("xpath of the elemt")).getLocation.GetY()
```

The GetX, GetY code may have some syntax error as I have not used any editor.

The given `X and Y should be greater than the previous found X,Y of static element`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi @Arun, thanks for you comment, Can you explain what you mean by `X and Y should be greater than the previous found X,Y of static element.`? after get `point (x,y)`, what should I do with it? How can I use this to check that the chat window is located at the `bottom left hand corner of the browser`?